# Blank spaces appearing while printing pdf from phantomjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf, phantomjs

Presently I am working on a project in which i have to generate a pdf from a webpage which contains some special symbols as well. so for generating it i am using Phantomjs(version 1.9.8). for this i have applied the following algorithm on my web page.

```
var heightTracker = 0;
var max_A4_page_height=842pt; // as size of A4 page is about 842 points
for every_division on page
var temp_height=Read_height_of_division(); // This give's height in pixels
temp_height*=(72/96); // Converting pixels to points
heightTracker+=temp_height;
if( heightTracker>= max_A4_page_height)
{
    Insert_Page_Break_Before_This_Division();
    heightTracker=temp_height; // Initial height of new page
}
```

The problem which i am facing is in many cases this is showing blank pages and if i reduce the A4 page height then my division element is broken into two pages and i got some blank space after that.

I have done some experiments on the above problem and get to know that the height of a division on my web page is different from height of a division on PDF i.e. in many cases the height is compressed by some factor.

Is anyone having idea why it is happening and how can i get out from this problem.

The current pdf is with 72 DPI. I also tried 120 DPI but no suitabe changes I found. In my pdf I also printed the height of each division and cumulative height of page. And [here is the pdf](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B17rEpr8xw5tdjJ0VzFXZXV2RlU).

Comment: Please share a sample PDF. Inspectingit we might be able to tell whether it is an issue of the PDF or the PDF viewer/printer.

Comment: The current pdf is with 72 DPI . I also tried 120 DPI but no suitabe changes i found.In my pdf i also printed the height of each division and cumulative height of page . and here is the pdf https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B17rEpr8xw5tdjJ0VzFXZXV2RlU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've built a related setup with PhantomJs and this sounds like it could very well be that the printed output does not have the correct CSS.

Test out that the printed content looks good in chrome (or likewise) first, and when the content works, then PhantomJs should be able to easily reproduce it.

Comment: in my page i am using a lot of jquery functions which keeps on changing font-size and font-family of the divisions .Is this also the case where phantomJS not able to read css styles and height properly.

Comment: PhantomJs should be able to understand your JavaScript, but it does introduce race conditions, since you need to ensure that all JavaScript is executed before printing. Consider validating the page is ready for print by polling for some content that is there only when all JavaScript has run.

Comment: Good to hear! And glad I could help :)